# Changing Button Background Removes Button Animation

Tags: android

I want to make the button transparent with making its colour the same as the background colour, but when I change the colour, it loses its default animation.

I've tried button.background = ColorDrawable("#fafafa") and button.setBackgroundColor(0xfafafa), both give the same result, but the latter supports earlier APIs.

```
val button = Button(this)
button.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 60F)
button.typeface = Typeface.SANS_SERIF
button.setBackgroundColor(0xfafafa)
```

has no animation, it just stays the same when touched on, but

```
val button = Button(this)
button.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 60F)
button.typeface = Typeface.SANS_SERIF
```

is just a default material design button, it works fine except for the colour.

I want the button to keep its animation even when its colour is changed. How could I do that?

Comment: Use `app:backgroundTint` in your layout XML. Or, [use `setBackgroundTintList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewCompat.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that button is created programmatically so the first solution wouldnt be possible, and the second one requires api 21, my target api is 14, i could use it but only if thats the only solution

Comment: "but that button is created programmatically" -- use `LayoutInflater` and inflate the layout. There is nothing forcing you to create the `Button` directly via the constructor. "the second one requires api 21" -- no, it does not. It requires *help* prior to API Level 21, the sort of help that you get from using AppCompat and [`AppCompatButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatButton.html). You automatically use `AppCompatButton` if you inflate layouts from an `AppCompatActivity` (or related fragment).

Comment: then ill try those, thanks a lot